# Abstract out Polars expressions with user-defined chainable functions on the `DataFrame`

Tags: node.js, nodejs-polars

### Motivation

Abstract out parametrized (via custom function parameters) chainable (preferably via the `DataFrame.prototype`) Polars expressions to provide user-defined, higher-level, reusable and chainable data analysis functions on the `DataFrame`

### Desired behavior and failed intent

```js
import pl from "nodejs-polars"
const { DataFrame, col } = pl

// user-defined, higher-level, reusable and chainable data analysis function
// with arbitrary complex parametrized Polars expressions
DataFrame.prototype.inc = function inc(column, x = 1, alias = `${column}Inc`) {
  return this.withColumn(col(column).add(x).alias(alias))
}
const df = new DataFrame({ a: [1, 2, 3] })
// works, but implies code duplication on reuse
console.log(df.withColumn(col("a").add(1).alias("aInc")))
// desiged behavior gives TypeError: df.inc is not a function
console.log(df.inc("a").inc("a", 2, "aInc2"))
```

What it the recommended way to define custom functions that encapsulate Polars expressions in `nodejs-polars`?

Comment: Modifying the prototype doesn't work since the DataFrame constructor doesn't use it when creating dataframes. You could manually add the `inc` function to each dataframe you want to use it on though.

Comment: I'm more looking for a standard DataFrame extension mechanism recommended by the community to universal application, rather then the `DataFrame.prototype` manipulation which may be one of possible options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a functional approach that does not require additional libraries would be to create a simple wrapper function & reexport polars with an overridden `DataFrame` method within your own package.

```js
// polars_extension.js
import pl from 'nodejs-polars'

const customMethods = {
  sumAlias() {
    return this.sum();
  },
};

export default {
  ...pl,
  DataFrame(...args) {
    return Object.assign(pl.DataFrame(...args), customMethods);
  }
}

// another_file.js
import pl from './polars_extension'

pl.DataFrame({num: [1, 2, 3]}).sumAlias()
```

Comment: It is a very nice solution which directly extends the `DataFrame` and gives  the familiar `DataFrame` interface (method chaining) even for user-defined custom extensions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Prototype-based solution

```js
function DF(df) { this.df = df }
DF.prototype.inc = function inc(column, x = 1, alias = `${column}Inc`) {
  this.df = this.df.withColumn(col(column).add(x).alias(alias))
  return this
}
const df = new DF(new DataFrame({ a: [1, 2, 3] }))
console.log(df.inc("a").inc("a", 2, "aInc2"))
```

### Functional programming solution (preferred)

```js
import { curry, pipe } from "rambda"
function inc(column, x, alias, df) {
  return df.withColumn(col(column).add(x).alias(alias))
}
const makeInc = curry(inc)
const df = new DataFrame({ a: [1, 2, 3] })
console.log(pipe(makeInc("a", 1, "aInc"), makeInc("a", 2, "aInc2"))(df))
```

### Output

````
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ aInc ┆ aInc2 │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64   │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0  ┆ 3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0 ┆ 3.0  ┆ 4.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0 ┆ 4.0  ┆ 5.0   │
└─────┴──────┴───────┘```
````